# Time Limit exceeding for http://www.spoj.com/problems/PRIME1/, Can anybody give me some tips to improve it?

Tags: java

Time Limit exceeding for http://www.spoj.com/problems/PRIME1/, Can anybody give me some tips to improve it?
Hi, I am posting my code here too, please have a look and give few suggestions to avoid time out.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.BitSet;

public class PrimeGenerator{
private static final int n=31624;
private static BitSet p=new BitSet(n);
private static BufferedReader getBufferedReader(){return new    BufferedReader(getInputStreamReader());}
private static InputStreamReader getInputStreamReader(){return new InputStreamReader(System.in);}
private static String getStringFromBR(BufferedReader bufferedReader) throws Exception{return bufferedReader.readLine();}
private static String[] splitString(String s){return s.split(" ");}
private static int getInteger(String s){return Integer.parseInt(s);}

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    findAllPrimes();
    BufferedReader br = getBufferedReader();
    String line = getStringFromBR(br);
    int t = getInteger(line);
    iterateForAllTestCases(br, t);
}

private static void iterateForAllTestCases(BufferedReader br, int t) throws Exception {

    for (int i=0; i<t; i++){
        String line=getStringFromBR(br);
        String a[]=splitString(line);
        long x=getInteger(a[0]);
        long y=getInteger(a[1]);
        printAllPrimes(x,y);
    }
}

private static void printAllPrimes(long x, long y){


        printAllPrimesUtil(x,y);


}

private static void printAllPrimesUtil(long x, long y){

    long i=x;
    long j;
    int flag;

    for( ;i<=y;i++){

        if(i<n){
            if(p.get((int) i)){
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }

        else{
            flag=0;
            innerLoop:
            for(j=2; (j*j)<i; j++){
                if (flag==1) break innerLoop;

                if(p.get((int) j)){
                    if(i%j==0){
                        flag=1;
                    }

                }
            }

            if(flag==0){
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    }
}


private static void findAllPrimes(){
    p.clear(0);
    p.clear(1);

    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++){
        p.set(i);
    }

    for(int i=2; (i*i)<=n ;i++){
        if (p.get(i)) {
            for (int j = 2*i; j <= n; j+=i) {
                p.clear(j);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I have ACed this problem before and I see your idea here, which seems on the right track. To solve the TLE problem, I would suggest:

1. First and foremost, in the second loop of `findAllPrimes()`, shouldn't the loop condition be `i <= n` instead of `(i*i) <= n`? Basically your program thinks all integers in `[sqrt(31624), 31624)` are primes...
2. Second, try if using primitive array like `boolean[]` or `int[]` works instead of `BitSet`.
3. Once you start using primitive array, use `int[]` to store **the ith prime** instead of using `boolean[]` to store **if i is a prime**. This can reduce the length of array and you will not need to calculate `j*j` on each cycle of the loop.

Hope they work and please let me know if it still suffers from TLE.